# copy files using bat file

Tags: batch-file, copy-paste

I Am trying like this

```
copy .\abc\\*.* .\Product_109\Course Library\Financial Statements-A Preview\util\
```

files  are kept in '`abc`' folder and trying to copy to the path (`Product_109\Course Library\Financial Statements-A Preview\util\`), destination path consists of spaces in between so it is not allowing me to copy.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:
Escaping spaces with a caret symbol (^) or put the path unter qoutes "":

```
copy .\abc*.* .\Product_109\"Course Library"\"Financial Statements-A Preview"\util\
or
copy .\abc*.* .\Product_109\Course^ Library\Financial^ Statements-A^ Preview\util\
or
copy .\abc*.* ".\Product_109\Course Library\Financial Statements-A Preview\util\"
```

Have no windows machine at the moment to test it. But one of these options should work.

Answer (score 0):

Put double quotes around paths with spaces in them:

```
copy .\abc\*.* ".\Product_109\Course Library\Financial Statements-A Preview\util\"
```

Answer (score 0):

Put double quotes around your second parameter:

`copy .\abc\*.* ".\Product_109\Course Library\Financial Statements-A Preview\util\"`